# MYSQL count() error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Author, count(Heading) AS "No. of books" FROM BOOKS GROUP BY Author;
```

Currently displays how many books each one of the authors has written.

How can I make the code return only the Authors who have written exactly 2 books?

Comment: Add after your group by Author: having count(Heading) = 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this!!!

```
SELECT Author, count(Heading) AS "No. of books"  
FROM BOOKS  
HAVING count(Heading)  = 2  
GROUP BY Author;
```

Comment: Try this: read the documentation of [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and/or try to run the query you suggest.

Comment: Hmm... it seems Oracle DB accepts the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses in any order. MySQL is a little more strict about that and it doesn't put the carriage in front of the horses.

Answer (score 0):

you can use having for filter the result for aggregated function

```
SELECT Author, count(Heading) AS "No. of books" 
FROM BOOKS 
GROUP BY Author
HAVING count(Heading)  = 2 ;
```